# Animating a diagonal scrolling animation to a rotated, absolute position image?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to scroll an absolute-position image so that it goes from the top of the image to the bottom of the image. I achieved it by changing the images' top / bottom properties on their hover state, but its behavior changes when a rotation transform is applied to it. I want it to scroll "in place" if that makes sense.

Shape/Image CSS

```css
.image-diagonal {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 0%;
  left: 20%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```css
.container:hover .image-diagonal {
  top: -100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46uaobv5/7/)

I created a sample fiddle made with colored divs instead of images, but the idea is the same. Shape 1 and 2 is the vertical-scrolling effect I achieved by changing the top and bottom values. Shape 3 and 4 are my attempts to a "diagonal" scroll and I seem to be missing a property or two to get it right. Shape 5 and 6 is my expected outcome after Shape 3 and 4 have completed the diagonal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap shape3 and shape4 in another element and add the rotation to that element instead of the individual child elements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).